# Django model foreign key removal

Tags: django, model

I have following model:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(DjangoUser, unique=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address,blank=True)

class Address(models.Model):
    (...)
```

Then I do:

```
client=Client()
client.address=address #any Address instance
client.save()
```

And now: how can I remove foreign association key from client?

```
client.address=None
```

seem not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to null out a foreign key, it's not enough to set in `blank`.  You must also specify that `null=True` is also set on the field.  See [The Difference Between Blank and Null](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/28/django-tips-difference-between-blank-and-null/).

Answer (score 1):

Your current models setup does not allow `null=True`, thus you cannot set it to `None`.

Comment: ah you were just a second faster than me

Answer (score 1):

```
address = models.ForeignKey(Address,blank=True, null=True)
```

the key is null=True as well as blank=True

also, make sure to syncdb etc